# Questions of Parliamentary Procedure

Tags: discussion, scope

Are question on the topics of parliamentary procedure on topic?

Comment: Does http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/q/160/37 answer your question?

Comment: @cpast no I am specifically wondering questions on the topic of Robert's Rules and other similar works are on topic

Comment: I would say, in the event there is not an SE community/site specific to legislative procedure or other similar site that deals with the parliamentary rules, I would lean toward yes. I cannot see what this shouldn't  fit into the law rubric in the absence of some more specific place to ask question related to this topic. Municipal lawyers deal with Roberts rules  all the time, which is typically where parliamentary procedure is derived from. It is where many rules of procedure that courts use today were originally derived from as well.